# What is the minimum distance that should be maintained between parallel electric and HDMI/Displayport cables?

Tags: electrical

I want to install HDMI and Displayport cables in the wall. What is the minimum distance I should keep between these cables and the electric wires?

Comment: The most important part of [Ecnerwal's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/244797/34147) is "are your video cables rated for in-wall installation?"

Comment: I have a couple of curious questions about that answer.  1) Isn't it the point of your HV wiring being in conduit, or in approved MC/NM jacket, that whatever is on the outside of the conduit/jacket is definitively, separated?  I can't think of any LV wiring in my house with HV ratings on the jacket .... phone, network, thermostat, none of it ... and it's all randomly snaked through walls.   There's no planned separation, other than that provided by the HV cables themselves.   2) At the risk of triggering the "no shopping brigade", can you find ANY HDMI or DP cable with an HV rating?

Comment: The inference you can make from the above is that you can't just throw AC power cords in a wall as if they were low-voltage cables.  To hide a TV AC cord, you need to properly install an outlet behind the TV, possibly fed from an inlet down below (if you want surge suppression).  If your TV uses a "wall wart" or other module to make low-voltage power, you are free to stick the low-voltage side in the walls.  There are pre-made kits which provide both a Code-legal AC wiring solution and a cable passage for everything else. Sold at home stores, avoid mail order for anything electrical.

Comment: The idea is to require two simultaneous failures before the HV and LV systems become improperly connected. CL3 HDMI cable: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1536164-REG/vanco_hd8k06_2_1_8k_60hz_premium_hdmi.html CL2 HDMI cable: https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=42674 CL2 Displayport cable: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1540199-REG/planar_systems_175_0936_00_6_displayport_cable.html

Comment: CL2 thermostat cable. Pretty much standard rating for thermostat wire unless getting into plenum-rated versions. https://www.supplyhouse.com/Honeywell-Genesis-47114807-500-ft-18-3-Solid-CL2-PVC-Honeywell-Genesis-Thermostat-Cable?gclid=Cj0KCQiAu62QBhC7ARIsALXijXRHU0oYbg_xYzsJaM7wB2pvq8BVbOMdhyGyLrFv6W2leG4426wJUu0aAiYZEALw_wcB  It generally won't say anything more obvious about voltage than than CL2 or CL3. I'll bet your thermostat cable is at least CL2.

Answer (score 5):

2" / 50mm is the (US-NEC) code separation requirement if the low voltage cable does not have insulation rated for line voltage, unless contained in conduit.

However, LV cables that are to be used in walls are supposed to be rated CL2 or CL3 - which means 150 or 300 volt insulation. At which point no separation is required.

Do not use "long patch cables not rated for in-wall use" as they are not suitable. If you cannot find the type of cable you need in a properly rated construction, you may be able to use converters to Cat6, fiber-optics, or Coax in-wall cables at each end.

Comment: The display cable and mains power cable on the computer I'm typing this on are 50mm apart **on the computer itself.** The vast majority of desktop computers  are installed with the power and signal cables going though the same hole in the desktop. But believe whatever made-up foolishness you want to believe. More separation won't hurt, but the question was minimum.

Comment: I’m not sure why you would be so rude as to call it foolish. I used to cable recording studios. Maybe we have different tolerances. Of course, the number of cheap computers with a permanent whine on the audio circuits shows some manufacturers struggle with this concept too.

Comment: @Tetsujin - 50/60Hz noise induced on an analog cable going to recording/data acquisition is bad, the digital HDMI or DVI signals really won't care that much.

Comment: In-wall separation is required depending on the rating of the cables, as noted in this answer.   I just looked at a bunch of my HDMI and DP cables, not one has an HV jacket rating.

Comment: But for noise/signal purposes if you are not building a recording studio, but installing a TV or a computer monitor in a house, and if you buy HDMI/DP cables that are even one step above complete POS, you won't need any separation.      Outside walls, almost everybody runs their power and signal cables twist-tied together for their entire length.  Video cables are shielded.  Unless they're total crap.

Comment: The difference between single-ended analog and differential twisted pair digital does, indeed, make it foolish to treat the latter as if it were the former. I used to run signals from pulsed-power plasma experiments to screen rooms full of oscilloscopes. I know a thing or 17 about signals in harsh noise environments. Doesn't mean I put HDMI cables inside copper pipes....

Comment: I'm pretty sure HDMI and DP are designed so that users don't have to worry about noise. A user could coil up one of these cables along with a power cable around a magnetic core without suffering noise as long as the cables are authentic, IE, built to HDMI/DP specs.   I believe OP's question was seeking the information in this answer about in-wall separation, not about crosstalk.